# How to check the pre-allocated database file of MongoDB is Used or not?

Tags: mongodb

We have been using MongoDB for a few weeks. One thing we could not understood is Pre-allocated file. Is there any way to check whether the pre-allocated file is currently used by MongoDB or not?

We have planned to implement "Quota File". So we need to ensure the pre-allocated file is currently used or not.

For Example, I have the database file as follows:

```
sgserver.0 ---> 16MB
sgserver.1 ---> 128MB
sgserver.2 ---> 256MB
sgserver.3 ---> 512MB
```

How do I check the pre-allocated file `sgserver.3` is used by MongoDB (for example, this database is used by any BSON or its Un-used)?

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Answer (score 3):

I am not very familiar with MongoDB, but from [this link](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Excessive+Disk+Space):

> As soon as a datafile starts to be used, the next one will be preallocated.

It seems to me that (on *nix at least), MongoDB will always have a datafile that is empty, or mostly empty. If it's writing heavy and filling up the file, the last file might have some data in it before a new empty file can be created.

> Additionally, on Unix, mongod will preallocate an additional datafile in the background and do background initialization of this file. **These files are prefilled with zero bytes.**

So to determine if it's used, check the file for non-zero bytes.

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on Derek's answer: the last datafile preallocated will be unused. Always. As soon as the first document is written to a pristine data file, a new datafile will be allocated in parallel. This is done in order to prevent unnecessary latency when the existing data files don't have sufficient (free) space for a write operation. So at the expense of disk space, performance is increased. Given the price of a few cents per GB, this is reasonable.

You might reduce the preallocated space needed for a new database by starting mongod with the `--smallfiles` option. However, as soon as the data file size for preallocated files reaches 2GB, the space advantage is eliminated.

Note: for non production environments, the preallocation of data files can be turned off altogether: see [the docs for storage.preallocDataFiles](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/#storage.preallocDataFiles) for details. Use at your own risk.